# Inherited website, unable to edit HTML code in Dreamweaver

Tags: html, coldfusion, dreamweaver

I'm going to start this off with I'm not a web developer, but know enough to make changes here and there. If my terminology is off, I can explain further.

We had an employee resign and now we're in charge of making website changes. I was able to pull the website files from FTP and am able to open it in Dreamweaver. The site was built on ColdFusion.

When I go to edit HTML, things are greyed out and I am unable to edit. I can view the code. I have the website setup for local development.

Any pointers? I'm hoping I'm overlooking a super simple thing :)

Comment: Just a guess, but the files might be read only.  If you are using Windows, you can open File Explorer, right click on the file, select Properties, and then select Security.  The relevant permissions will be there.

Comment: Found the issue. The developer actually had the HTML in a database field and it was parsing it live. Now it makes sense why I couldn't edit it.

Comment: Do you have any code to show what that looks like. It might be useful for the next person with a similar problem.

Comment: Dreamweaver has the ability to make templates with regions of code being un-editable. To get around this, see this guide from Adobe. https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/editing-content-template-based-document.html

Comment: A screenshot would be worth a thousand words but it does sound a lot like what I remember of Dreamweaver templates decades ago, despite the response saying it was HTML in a DB field (which I wasn't aware Dreamweaver could display live?). For anyone else with a similar issue, you can confirm the presence of DW templates by opening the source files in a plain text editor and checking for the presence of DW template comments, eg `<!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="..." -->` and `<!-- InstanceBegin template="..." -->` and others: https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/dreamweaver/using/template-syntax.html